# Getting the id of an element that triggered an event

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to create a modal by clicking on an area, and then modyfing it in different ways depending on which area was clicked. I reached a stall because I was giving all my areas the same id, meaning that my code would only modify the modal using the data of the first area. Is there a way, after giving every area an unique id, to take it and put it in the function?

```js
$("#ModArea").click(function() {
  var name = $(this).attr('title');
  $("#country_name").html(name);
});
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */

.modal fade {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}


/* Add Animation */

@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: white;
}

.modal-body {
  padding: 2px 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="europe_img" src="https://mapswire.com/download/europe/europe-political-map-miller.jpg" usemap="#europe" alt="Europe">

<map name="europe">
        <area id="ModArea" target="" alt="Iceland" title="Iceland" coords="138,388,35,540,232,748,549,585,516,374"
              shape="poly" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal">
        <area id="ModArea" target="" alt="Ireland" title="Ireland" coords="791,1240,644,1337,635,1568,846,1496,866,1304"
              shape="poly" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal">
        <div class="modal fade" id="Modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle"
             aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="country_name"></h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        ...
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</map>
```

Right now if I click on Ireland it creates a modal with an empty title, while if I click on Iceland, or click on Ireland after clicking on Iceland, it creates a modal with "Iceland" as the tile.

Comment: The `id` attribute name must be unique, as only the first one will be retrieved, which is Iceland based on your code. Change `id="ModArea"` to `class="ModArea"`, and also change the `$("#ModArea")` selector to `$(".ModArea")`, should help it work as expected.